# Getting a specific cell from specific row and column out of MySQL database, jdbc, java

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, cell

I'm trying to get a specifc customer id out of a MySQL table from a telephone number input from the user to use it to add a new order to that customer id. I'm trying to use a method that creates a list being filled by resultset but I keep being returned nothing, more specificly empty square brackets "[]"

This is the code im using.

```
if((getCustomerID.getCustomerID(inputContactNumber).toString()).equals("[]")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Customer phone number does not exist.\nTry again or create new customer.");
            return;
        } else {
            customerID = Integer.parseInt(getCustomerID.getCustomerID(inputContactNumber).toString());

            insertOrder.insertOrder(customerID);
        }
```

getCustomerID():

```
public List<Customer> getCustomerID(String phoneNumber) throws SQLException{
    List<Customer> customerList = new ArrayList();

    String selectCustomerID = "SELECT idcustomer FROM customer WHERE contactNumber = " + phoneNumber;

    try {
        MyConnection mc = new MyConnection();
        dbConnection = mc.getConnection();
        statement = dbConnection.createStatement();

        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(selectCustomerID);

        while (rs.next()){
            int customerID = rs.getInt("idcustomer");

            Customer c;
            c = new Customer (customerID);
            customerList.add(c);
        }
    } 
    catch (SQLException e){
        System.err.println(e);
        return null;
    }
    finally{
        if (statement != null){
            statement.close();
        }
        if (dbConnection != null){
            dbConnection.close();
        }
    }
    return customerList;
}//end of getGetCustomerID()
```

Any input is greatly appreciated

-Edit-
MyConnection()

```
public class MyConnection {
public Connection connection = null;

public Connection getConnection()
{
     System.out.println("---- MySql Connecting ----");

     try {
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
     } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
         System.out.println("Can't find MySQl Driver.");
         e.printStackTrace();
     }

     System.out.println("Driver Registered.");

     try {
         connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/quotedb","root","");
     } catch  (SQLException e) {
         System.out.println("Connection Failed.");
     }

     if (connection != null) {
         System.out.println("Connection Established.");
     } else {
         System.out.println("Connection Failed.");
     }

     return connection ;
}
```

Comment: In your DB, is the `contactNumber` column a number or varchar?

Comment: contactNumber is a varchar

Comment: aye you sure it is making the connection please share the MyConnection class

Comment: It prints to console when it successfully connects and i've used the same class to insert rows, so im pretty certain it's connecting. Edited it in anyway

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried executing this query in a SQL Programm? As it looks like simply no result is returned, thus the empty square brackets which is the String equivalent of an empty Array.

toString() on an Array is generally a bad idea, you better use length to determine if the Array is empty. Furthermore it is not clear if the result should be unique or not: 
If the function getCustomerID.getCustomerID(inputContactNumber) returns more than one result you try to parse a Int like [3453,3543] which will never be what you want. Instead you should use .get(0) on the Array to retrieve the first element.

Comment: Yeah i've run the same thing through the MySQL console and it returns the id

Comment: Thanks for the length and get(0) ideas though, knew I was doing something dodgy with the list

Answer (score 0):

Please change your select query to

```
"SELECT idcustomer FROM customer WHERE contactNumber = '"+phoneNumber+"'"
```

it will work fine i hope

Comment: Have you verified this? AFAIK, it does not matter if the quotes are present or not for an INT type of field.

Comment: @Nikhil Talreja she clearly said `contactNumber is a varchar `

Answer (score 0):

Change the if condition to:

```
if(getCustomerID(inputContactNumber) == null || getCustomerID(inputContactNumber).isEmpty()){
```